# How to initialise 2d array with all elements are 0?

Tags: c

I want to initialise a 2d array having all its elements are 0.
I have tried this:

```
scanf("%d",&n);
int arr[n][n]={0};
```

but i got the [Error]:"variable-sized object may not be initialized"

So,how to do this?

Comment: When I used static int arr[n][n],I got this:                     [Error] storage size of 'a' isn't constant

Comment: I have a suggestion: do not use VLAs, use dynamic allocation instead: `int *arr = calloc(n * n, sizeof *arr);`

Comment: I used calloc it says:[error]: "two few arguments to function 'calloc'"

Comment: my bad, edited ... after that you need to validate `arr` and calculate every access to the array by `n * row + col`

Comment: @pmg Too easy to use calloc. If there is an easy and there is a needlessly complicated solution, always roll with the needlessly complicated one :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Be explicit.

```
#include <string.h>

const int got = scanf("%d", &n);
int arr[n][n];
memset(arr, 0, sizeof arr);
```

Note that if `got` isn't 1, the above has undefined behavior. This is pretty dangerous.

Comment: It gives me :                                                             [Warning] incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'memset' [enabled by default]

Comment: @madhurgarg You need `#include <string.h>`, that was considered well-known. I added it.

Comment: Sorry! for my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Do in two steps:

```
int a[n][n];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
   for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
   {
      a[i][j] = 0;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

probably the simplest method

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        a[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `#include<string.h>`
library
well we have three methods to initialise it to 0

```
// the best and easy is using memset

int n;
scanf("%d",&n);
int array_d[n][n];

memset(array_d,0,sizeof(array_d));
```

// syntax memset(address_of_arr,anyvalue_u_want_Tointialise,sizeof_the_array_or_bytes);
//hope u get it

case 2
// if it is global array then

```
int arr[1000][1000]={0};
```

case 3

```
//using for loop

for(int =i;i<n;i++)
{

for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
{
arr[i][j]=0;
}

}
```